# Deleting/removing a cookie itself and not just the value

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, cookies

The following code only removes the cookie value only but the cookie itself remains:

```
public static void expiryCookie(SlingHttpServletResponse response, 
                String cookieName, String cookieValue) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cookieName);
            sb.append("=");
            sb.append(cookieValue);
            sb.append("0");
            sb.append("0");
            sb.append(";path=");
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(";domain=");
            sb.append(".xyz.com");
            if(isSecureCookie()) {
                sb.append(";secure");
            }
            sb.append(";HttpOnly");
            response.addHeader("SET-COOKIE", sb.toString());

        }
```

or a code like:

```
curCookie.setValue(null);
    curCookie.setMaxAge(0);
    curCookie.setPath("/");
```

How do I delete/remove a cookie altogether. This will prevent any other code to check for this cookie and set a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cookie as persistent in the past by adding `;expires=1 Jan 1970 10:00:00`. Browsers will delete it

Comment: that doesn't remove the cookie, only value.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `maxAge = 0` should do it.

```
public static void deleteCookie(HttpServletResponse httpResponse, String cookieName, String context) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    cookie.setPath(context != null ? context : "/");
    httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

[Cookie#setMaxAge](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge(int)) from Servlet 3.1 API Documentation - Apache Tomcat 8.0.39

> public void setMaxAge(int expiry) 
>   Sets the maximum age of the cookie in seconds.  ...  A zero value
>   causes the cookie to be deleted.